# Unmarshaling a json http response

Tags: json, utf-8, go

I have very recently started playing with GO and I am trying to unmarshal a JSON response from http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json.
For some reason that I can't understand the unmarshaling failed, the unmarshalled struct is empty (my guess is that it is somehow related to encoding).

Below is the code, any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Itay

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "net/http"
  "encoding/json"
)

const alertsUrl = "http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json"

type Record struct {
  Id string `json:id`
  Title string `json:title`
  Data []string `json:data`
}

func main() {
  client := &http.Client{}
  req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", alertsUrl, nil)
  perror(err)

  req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
  res, err := client.Do(req)
  perror(err)

  defer res.Body.Close()
  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
  perror(err)

  var record Record
  json.Unmarshal(body, &record)
  fmt.Println(record)
}

func perror(err error) {
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: **Stop** ignoring errors, check all your errors before ever asking a question on here.

Comment: @Wessie do you mind telling me which error I ignored?

Comment: Ah... well, I am not very familiar with go. Checking again I can see that the Unmarshal method has an error returned in its signature. I'll try walking this path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ignoring the error on [JSON Unmarshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
```

See that it returns an error. Adding that in,

```
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &record)
perror(err)
```

It looks like this is a Unicode error — you need to [decode the UTF-16 data](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/).

How should you do this? Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783830/how-to-read-utf16-text-file-to-string-in-golang). Basically once you read the body like `body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)`, you want to decode the UTF-16 bytes to a string. There is a lot going on there, but we can take some liberties: for instance, pulling up the URL in Chrome, the browser tells us that it is UTF-16 LE. So we can skip the ByteOrder detection. So the key here is this function:

```
func UTF16BytesToString(b []byte, o binary.ByteOrder) string {
    utf := make([]uint16, (len(b)+(2-1))/2)
    for i := 0; i+(2-1) < len(b); i += 2 {
        utf[i/2] = o.Uint16(b[i:])
    }
    if len(b)/2 < len(utf) {
        utf[len(utf)-1] = utf8.RuneError
    }
    return string(utf16.Decode(utf))
}
```

Knowing our byte order and passing it in, this will convert the naïve byte array to a string of UTF-16 characters. Thanks to user OneOfOne's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681644/unmarshaling-a-json-http-response/24683083?noredirect=1#comment38275552_24683083), we can also detect the BOM easily.

The result:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "unicode/utf16"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

const alertsUrl = "http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json"

type Record struct {
    Id    string   `json:id`
    Title string   `json:title`
    Data  []string `json:data`
}

// LazyUTF16BytesToString converts UTF-16 encoded bytes, in big or little endian byte order,
// to a UTF-8 encoded string.
func LazyUTF16BytesToString(b []byte) string {
    if len(b)%2 != 0 {
        panic("len(b) % 2 != 0")
    }

    var codec binary.ByteOrder = binary.LittleEndian
    if b[0] == 0xFE && b[1] == 0xFF { //check and strip the BOM
        b = b[2:]
        codec = binary.BigEndian
    } else if b[0] == 0xFF && b[1] == 0xFE {
        b = b[2:]
    }

    utf := make([]uint16, (len(b)+(2-1))/2)
    for i := 0; i+(2-1) < len(b); i += 2 {
        utf[i/2] = codec.Uint16(b[i:])
    }
    if len(b)/2 < len(utf) {
        utf[len(utf)-1] = utf8.RuneError
    }
    return string(utf16.Decode(utf))
}

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", alertsUrl, nil)
    perror(err)

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    perror(err)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    perror(err)

    bodyString := LazyUTF16BytesToString(body)

    var record Record
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyString), &record)
    perror(err)
    fmt.Println(record)
}

func perror(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: so... the Unmarshal method gets a byte array. how can the decoding result can be Unmarshalled?

Comment: You need to do the decoding before unmarshalling. Detail added.

Comment: One last thing - you mentioned that chrome tells us that the encoding UTF-16 LE. Where did you pull this data from?

Comment: The first character is the BOM character.

Comment: @OneOfOne, thanks! I guess that's what I get for skipping the byte order check in the answer. ItayKaro View->Encoding, Chrome checks the UTF-16LE mark.

Comment: Thanks OneOfOne, pswaminathan.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/v_BNwXpKyD the utf16tostring function with a bom checker, assumes LE if there's no BOM.