# How to open a file with specific encoding in golang?

Tags: go

In Python, we have something like

```
open("filepath", encoding="utf8")
```

How to do that in golang while reading a file?

Comment: Files are collections of bytes. Go `string` supports UTF8 - that can also store sequences of bytes that may or may not be valid UTF8. To check if a read sequence of bytes is valid use [unicode.utf8](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#Valid)

Answer (score 9):

In Go files are always accessed on a byte level, unlike python which has the notion of text files. Strings in go [are implicitly UTF-8](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals) so you can simply convert the bytes gotten from a file to a string if you want to interpret the contents as UTF-8:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    dat, err := os.ReadFile("/tmp/dat")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(dat))
}
```

If you want to read files in any other encoding you will need to do some manual conversion, [UTF-16 to UTF-8 for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783830/how-to-read-utf16-text-file-to-string-in-golang)

Comment: Nitpick: string literals that contain byte escapes may not be valid UTF-8.