# Encoding Problem when writing inside a file

Tags: go, encoding

Hi i'm coding something in golang, that's retreive the content of the bin file (of notepad) on windows and the output is weird

```
                                                                                                                                             r   e   g   e   r   g
```

Like that and i would like to know how to decode that here's my code !

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func utf16Decode(b []byte) string {
    var str strings.Builder
    r := bytes.NewReader(b)
    var utf16Bytes [2]byte

    for {
        if _, err := r.Read(utf16Bytes[:1]); err != nil {
            break
        }
        unicodeChar := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(utf16Bytes[:])
        str.WriteRune(rune(unicodeChar))
    }

    return str.String()
}
func write(contentToAppend string) {
    tempDir := os.Getenv("TEMP") + "\\RnsLMp_LOG" // Adjust for your OS if needed
    err := os.MkdirAll(tempDir, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = os.WriteFile(tempDir+"\\test.txt", []byte(contentToAppend), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}

func clear(filename string) {
    tempDir := os.Getenv("TEMP") + "\\RnsLMp_LOG" // Adjust for your OS if needed
    err := os.MkdirAll(tempDir, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = os.WriteFile(tempDir+"\\test.txt", []byte("e"), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

}

func main() {
    defer func() {

        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            return
        }
    }()

    appDataDir := os.Getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")
    directoryRelative := `Packages\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\TabState`
    fullPath := filepath.Join(appDataDir, directoryRelative)
    listOfBinFiles, _ := filepath.Glob(filepath.Join(fullPath, "*.bin"))
    for _, fullFilePath := range listOfBinFiles {
        if strings.HasSuffix(fullFilePath, ".0.bin") || strings.HasSuffix(fullFilePath, ".1.bin") {
            continue
        }
        contents, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(fullFilePath)
        is_saved_file := contents[3]
        if string(is_saved_file) != "" {
            lengthOfFilename := int(contents[4])
            filenameEnding := 5 + lengthOfFilename*2
            originalFilename := string(contents[5:filenameEnding])

            delimeterStart := bytes.Index(contents[filenameEnding:], []byte{0x00, 0x01}) + filenameEnding
            delimeterEnd := bytes.Index(contents[filenameEnding:], []byte{0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}) + filenameEnding

            fileMarker := contents[delimeterStart+2 : delimeterEnd]
            fileMarker = fileMarker[:len(fileMarker)/2]

            originalFileContents := contents[delimeterEnd+4+len(fileMarker) : len(contents)-5]
            decodedContent := utf16Decode(originalFileContents)
            decodedContent = strings.ReplaceAll(decodedContent, "\r", "\n")

            data := "\n" + originalFilename + "\n" + decodedContent + "\n" + strings.Repeat("=", 25)
            write(data)

        } else {
            lengthOfFilename := int(contents[4])
            filenameEnding := 5 + lengthOfFilename*2
            originalFilename := string(contents[5:filenameEnding])

            delimeterStart := bytes.Index(contents, []byte{0x00, 0x01})
            delimeterEnd := bytes.Index(contents, []byte{0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00})

            fileMarker := contents[delimeterStart+2 : delimeterEnd]
            fileMarker = fileMarker[:len(fileMarker)/2]

            originalFileContents := contents[delimeterEnd+4+len(fileMarker) : len(contents)-5]
            decodedContent := utf16Decode(originalFileContents)
            decodedContent = strings.ReplaceAll(decodedContent, "\r", "\n")

            data := "\n" + originalFilename + "\n" + decodedContent + "\n" + strings.Repeat("=", 25)
            write(data)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of encoding/*decoding nothing worked out i want it to be

regerg
and not
r   e   g   e   r   g

Comment: 1. Don't throw away errors like with `ioutil.ReadFile`. 2. Use OS-agnostic wrappers like `os.MkdirTemp()`. 3. Without an example file, we can't really know what's going on. We need a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In addition to what coxley exlained about reproducable input: You are not handling surrogate pairs at all.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Go already has character set conversion utilities built in. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783830/how-to-read-utf16-text-file-to-string-in-golang

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share `hexdump` of your file (relevant part only, canonical hex+ASCII display).